# Can I get the output of a independent background job again? (e.g. a job run in `screen`, and I close the terminal)

Tags: bash, terminal, background-process, recovery

as described in title:
    first:I run `screen` in terminal
    second:run `ping google.com`
    then:I press <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to exit to normal terminal and close it

And I want to know if I can get the output of command `ping google` again?

Comment: how did u *exit to normal terminal*?

Comment: you can type Ctrl+A+D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you press `<c-a> d` the screen session will continue running in background and closing the "normal terminal" would not kill the screen. Afterwards you can re-attach to the screen session with `screen -r`.